# Make Fieldset border match TextArea

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to make the border around a fieldset more snug to a textarea? Consider:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Note Edit</legend>
  <textarea rows="30" cols="80" id="myTextArea">
  </textarea>
</fieldset>
```

...unfortunately, the right-hand fieldset border extends all the way to the far-right of the browser screen, leaving a gap between the right-hand borders of the textarea and the fieldset.

What's the best way to resolve this? [W3School's fieldset tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) doesn't mention anything about sizing fieldsets or their borders.

Using IE9 on a Win7 machine.

Comment: You can remove the padding and float it left.

Comment: @j08691: that would work, but because adding a float property for that element would cause formatting issues for the rest of the page I'm curious if better options are available?

Comment: All you'd need to do to fix that is clear the first element that follows the fieldset.

Comment: @j08691: good point, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following CSS:

```
fieldset {
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}
```

The borders of the fieldset are almost 'attached' to the textarea.

You can see this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/Cu2Nv/1

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't take care of it. Difficult to tell with small jsfiddle result frame, but the issue is still there.

Comment: @AaronThomas I missed the display property. I've edited my answer. Please take a look!!

Comment: @AaronThomas You can make use of `float:left` as j08691 mentions. In case, you don't want to use it then you can make use of 'display:inline'. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: That takes care of it, I like it.